# How do I configure MVC 4 razor routing to hide the Multiple controllers name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to routing to hide the Multiple controllers name which I have below

`Homecontroller`, `Admincontroller`, `Usercontroller`

This for each controller I want to root so for hide a controller Folder in 
Web browser. so user can able to see only action like this

1. www.domain.com/Login
2. www.domain.com/AmdinDashboard
3. www.domain.com/UserDashboard

how do i can hide Multiple controllers?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by defining the routing in RouteConfig.cs for each of www.domain.com/Login, www.domain.com/AmdinDashboard and www.domain.com/UserDashboard.

Lets say for www.domain.com/Login you can add map in route config as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Login",
           url: "Login",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

This will send the request to controller Home and action Login when url www.domain.com/Login is requested.

Answer (score 0):

use attribute routing - simply add

```
 [Route("Login")]
 public ActionResult Login()
```

you'll also need to make sure that you've added the following line to your RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```